# How does apply-templates work?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have just started learning XSL(T) and I wonder how `apply-templates` work? I do not understand the recursively applies templates part of it as it is written in my book.

I understand the XPath-part of XSL(T) and so on but not what `apply-templates` is doing and why I write it multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've read about apply-templates in a book but haven't understood it, then it's not clear that a few words here will help. Perhaps you need a different book: different tutorial styles appeal to different people. Or perhaps an online tutorial such as http://vimeo.com/15234803 will get the ideas across.

The essence of the template mechanism is that there are two parties involved. The xsl:apply-templates instruction selects some nodes for processing, and the template rules (between them) decide what that processing should be. This gives very loose coupling and great separation of concerns; it's rather like object-oriented message/method despatch, but much more flexible.

Comment: Please post the some oher XSLT video tutorials link.Bcoz the above tutorials gives the clear idea of apply-templates and also i need to know the purpose of using mode='parent'...

Comment: Let me recommend my book: XSLT 2.0 Programmers Reference from Wrox Press. Once you're into things like named modes, you need a decent reference book.

Answer (score 26):

You use `<xsl:apply-templates>` to invoke the `<xsl:template>`:s you have defined.

`<xsl:apply-templates>` calls a matching template for each node in the set.

You can control processing order by specifying a `select` attribute on `apply-templates`.

See this example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_apply_templates.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- The first `apply-templates` calls the `cd` template each time an element named `"cd"` is encountered.
- The `cd` template, in turn calls the `title` and `artist` templates to process the children elements of `<cd>`.
- `title` is processed before `artist`. Note, that the order of `artist` and `title` elements in the source XML makes no difference.

You could think of `apply-templates` as analoguous to a subroutine call in procedural languages.