# Extract text through XSL by skipping content within given children

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to extract the text of an interesting node (here `big-structured-text`) but within this node there are some children I would like to skip (here `title`, `subtitle`, and `code`). Those "to remove" nodes can have children.

Sample data:

```
<root>
    <big-structured-text>
        <section>
            <title>Introduction</title>
            In this part we describe Australian foreign policy....
            <subsection>
                <subtitle>Historical context</subtitle>
                After its independence...
                <meta>
                    <keyword>foreign policy</keyword>
                    <keyword>australia</keyword>
                    <code>
                        <value>XXHY-123</value>
                        <label>IRRN</label>
                    </code>
                </meta>
            </subsection>
        </section>
    </big-structured-text>
    <!-- ... -->
    <big-structured-text>
        <!-- ... -->
    </big-structured-text>
</root>
```

So far I've tried:

```
<xsl:for-each
     select="//big-structured-text">
         <text>
             <xsl:value-of select=".//*[not(*)
                 and not(ancestor-or-self::code)
                 and not(ancestor-or-self::subtitle)
                 and not(ancestor-or-self::title)
                 ]" />
         </text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but this does just take the node that don't have any children, it will take `keyword` but not the text following the introduction title

I've also tried:

```
<xsl:for-each
     select="//big-structured-text">
         <text>
             <xsl:value-of select=".//*[
                 not(ancestor-or-self::code)
                 and not(ancestor-or-self::subtitle)
                 and not(ancestor-or-self::title)
                 ]" />
         </text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But this is echoing multiple time the interesting text and sometime the uninteresting one (every node is iterate once for itself and then one time per ancestor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than for-each you could approach this using templates.  The [default behaviour](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) when you apply-templates to an element node is simply to recursively apply them to all its child nodes (which includes text nodes as well as other elements), and for a text node to output the text.  Therefore all you need to do is create empty templates to squash the elements you *don't* want and then let the default templates do the rest.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/big-structured-text" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="big-structured-text">
    <text><xsl:apply-templates /></text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- empty template means anything inside any of these elements will be
       ignored -->
  <xsl:template match="title | subtitle | code" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input this produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><text>


            In this part we describe Australian foreign policy....


                After its independence...

                    foreign policy
                    australia




    </text><text>

    </text></root>
```

You may wish to investigate the use of `<xsl:strip-space>` to get rid of some of the extraneous whitespace, but with mixed content you always have to be careful not to strip out too much.

Comment: Can you detail in your code what part is telling to copy what do not fall within the given tags ?

Comment: @AsTeR there isn't anything explicit in my code to do that - it's a result of the default rules I linked to in the first line.  These default rules are essentially equivalent to `<xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` and `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>`.  The thing that makes it work is that the explicit `match="title | subtitle | code"` template overrides the default `"*"` one.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I'll try that after a good sleep ;)

Comment: Okay that worked, can you explain a bit more about how xsl:template and xsl:apply-templates work or point a relevant link about that? I still don't really understand how to use them.

Comment: @AsTeR then you should definitely learn :-) - template matching is where the real power of XSLT comes from.  Using templates you separate the two issues of _which_ nodes to process and _what_ to do with each one.  [This is the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#rules) defining template rules but it's a bit dry reading, [Michael Kay suggests a video tutorial in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051442/592139), or I'm sure there are countless others on the web (just avoid anything from w3schools).

Comment: Many thanks, I'm avoiding XSLT and this is not anything of my domain, but sometime it's just the perfect tool. I'm already running for w3schools, but they are glued to Google top results which doesn't help!

Comment: @AsTeR the other thing to be careful about is what version of XSLT a tutorial refers to.  XSLT 2.0 has features that are much more powerful than 1.0 and make programming some cases much simpler but (far too) many libraries only support 1.0, and some tutorials don't make it clear what version they are based on.